# How to delete a specific index in a list and how to break the loop when you are finished with the input of the user

Tags: python, list

I want to delete the 2nd and fourth user input and i would like to end the program when the user has an invalid input

```
num_elements = []

list_length = int(input('Enter number of elems: '))

while True:
try:
    for i in range(list_length):
        item = int(input('Enter the numbers: '))
        num_elements.append(item)
        del (num_elements[0])
        del (num_elements[3])
        break

except:
    print('Invalid Input!!!')
    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like you tried to make the user enter valid numbers only, but put the `try/except` in the wrong place and then added a `while` loop to repair that ending up with being prompted for more numbers than required.

I've no idea what all the `break`s and `del`s are about.

You meant to write this:

```py
num_elements = []

list_length = int(input('Enter number of elems: '))

for i in range(list_length):
    while True:
        try:
            item = int(input('Enter the numbers: '))
            num_elements.append(item)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid Input!!!')

print(num_elements)
```

Comment: How can i delete the 2nd and fourth number from the list though?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: because i want to know how can i delete the 2nd and 4th number in the list sorry i just wanna learn how :'>

Comment: Do you mean that you want to delete those items after the list is constructed, or not store those elements as the user enters them? What about if the user requests to only enter 2 items?

Comment: i mean i would like the program to just print the 2nd and 4th item :D and the program will end if the user has an invalid input

Comment: So, just print those as the user is entering them? Or just `print(num_elements[1],num_elements[3])` at the end?

Comment: 1 more thing though, i want the two numbers to be printed like this: ['2', '4']  when the user entered 4 elements and their input is 1 2 3 and 4 also, when i entered an invalid character like a letter the program is still running and i want to fix that by stopping the whole program

Comment: Number 1 is: `print([str(num_elements[i]) for i in [1,3]])`, but the second means moving the `try` before the `for` loop and the `except ValueError:` below the final `print()`